# Young adult book (series?) about children who develop powers — a character with silver skin

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, powers

First-time poster here.

This is a book I remember from when I was 10-12, which would have been 2003-2005ish. It’s possible that it was later, but I remember it being around the mid 2000s.

The premise of the book was that children (maybe just people in general but I remember it being children) begin developing mysterious powers, mostly psychic, around the world. I believe that these people feel a “calling” to a specific spot in the world and all begin traveling there and meeting up.

I distinctly remember there being some sort of beast from outer space (I think a gigantic snake) traveling into the solar system and towards Earth. I remember this being why the children start developing the powers and gathering together. I don’t remember if the people are there to welcome this beast or to prevent it from destroying the planet.

I also distinctly remember a main character who was a young boy who developed psychic powers. I think he was bald and his skin had turned silver? He seemed to be a “chosen one” who was more powerful than others. This detail may be wrong though.

I don’t remember much else about the characters or plot, sorry!

I’ve casually searched for this book through the years but haven’t found anything through google, so if anyone has ideas I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be *[The Silver Child](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?152395)* by Cliff McNish? It is a novel from 2003, the first installment of McNish's *[Silver Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Sequence)* trilogy.

From [McNish's website](https://www.cliffmcnish.com/the-silver-child/):

> It concerns a group of children - six children - who are drawn to a
> deserted wind-swept wasteland called Coldharbour. The only things
> living in Coldharbour are a few seagulls and some well-fed rats living
> off the rubbish dumps. There is no food or shelter. The only other
> people there are groups of dangerous gang kids.
>
> Nevertheless, the six children have to find a way to survive, and over
> time they discover that they also have amazing powers.

In particular, one of the children, Milo, has skin that first turns gold, and then changes to silver as his powers develop and he turns into the titular "Silver Child".

The point of the children joining together and developing powers is to defend the Earth against a force known only as "the Roar": a giantic space creature coming to devour the world.

Comment: That’s exactly it, and you think my brain would’ve remembered that title given the few things I remember of the book! I guess some things were misremembered. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help @SpicyBoi  Can you click the checkmark to "accept" my answer - then people will know the question has been answered.